# Where to store calibration data?

Tags: ros, calibration, data, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a list of integers, returned from my IMU, that represent calibration settings. I need to load these into the IMU on every power-up. Since the settings are unique to my IMU, I don't want to commit them to version control. Is there some standard ROS location for storing small data files, such as calibration values, where I can store these values?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262741/where-to-store-calibration-data?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I typically *do* store these things in a VCS, but then in a special package that only contains that (those) file(s).

If you then include the serial nr (or something similar) in the name of the file, it's clear that those parameters are for that particular device.

The only thing you have to do now is add something to your launch file (fi) that loads the file and initialises your IMU with the parameters.

As an example: in my lab we have a package specifically for Kinect (v2) calibrations, called `iai_kinect2_$labname_calibration_data`, which contains the calibration for several of our Kinects. The launch files that tie our setups together then load the appropriate one.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PickBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/26245/pickbot/) on 2017-05-29**:
How do you handle 2d cameras with a lense that require a new calibration after e.g. a refocus?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-29**:
We've only very few of those, and if the device supports profiles with such settings we store those with the calibration data. If not, then we don't have a procedure, as manual focus adjustments will never be exact enough.

I've seen people fork the calibration pkgs then and manage their own data.